# Node.js on Windows: upgrade or uninstall & reinstall?

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-7

I am on Windows 7 and I need to have a newer specific version of node.js than one currently installed. What is the recommended approach: upgrade to newer specific version OR uninstall current version and then install the newer specific version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use lastest LST from https://nodejs.org/en/ : 10.16.0 LST